# round only input that is numeric otherwise skip in R

Tags: r, function, rounding

I was wondering if there is a way to customize `round` in R such that if one inputs non-numerics (ex. `"No"`), the `round` would just output the non-numeric as it is  but just round the other numeric input?

Here is what I tried with no success:

```
a = c(.56789, "No", .87542) ## round numerics but just output the non-numeric

roundif <- function(x, digits) if(any(!is.numeric(x))) x else round(x, digits)

roundif(a, 2)
```

Comment: @akrun, is that a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to create a logical index for subsetting the numeric elements.  In the function, `grepl`, will check if there any alphabets (`[A-Za-z]`) in an elements.  It could be further generalized to include other characters (if needed)

```
roundif <- function(x, digits) {
          i1 <- grepl('[A-Za-z]', x) # logical index
           x1 <- as.list(x) # convert to a list
           x1[!i1] <- round(as.numeric(a[!i1]), digits) # assign rounded values 
           x1

   }

roundif(a, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.57

#[[2]]
#[1] "No"

#[[3]]
#[1] 0.88
```

NOTE: The `vector` is converted to a `list` as `vector` can hold only a single `type`

Comment: @rnorouzian  then you need a `list` as `vector` support only a single class

Comment: @rnorouzian  I modified the function.

Comment: Follow-up if the input is a `data.frame` instead of a vector (e.g., `a = data.frame(a = .56789, b = "No", d = .87542)`), the function won't work, right?

Comment: @rnorouzian  In that case,, I assume the types are already right ones?  If that ist the case, `df1 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)`